# debugging errors.. how to remedy?

Tags: functions, errors, debug

I had trouble accessing wp-login.php, so I changed the name of the theme I'm developing to force WP to switch to default. I then turned on debugging and received the errors below. I'm a little puzzled as to why these have come about because they were not showing when I was last working on the theme a few days ago, and I've used get_bloginfo in other themes without issue. Any and all help re: how to fix these errors is greatly appreciated.

Notice: get_bloginfo was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.2! The siteurl option is deprecated for the family of bloginfo() functions. Use the url option instead. in /home3/dyluxept/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3551

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/dyluxept/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3551) in /home3/dyluxept/public_html/wp-content/themes/smallbiz/functions.php on line 141

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/dyluxept/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3551) in /home3/dyluxept/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `get_bloginfo( 'siteurl' )` with `home_url()`.

As [the `get_bloginfo()` Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) explains, `siteurl` is *deprecated*:

> `'siteurl' / 'home (note this is deprecated! from version 2.2)' / 'url'` - Returns the `'Site address (URL)'` set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the `'home'` record in the `wp_options` table. **Consider using `home_url()` instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You also seem to have a problem in the theme. From the second error:

> /wp-content/themes/smallbiz/functions.php on line 141

You'll want to examine that line of the theme's `functions.php` file.

This is just a guess, but one common cause of an error like this is white space that comes after the closing PHP tag like this:

```
?>
_
```

(That underscore is a space.)

You don't even need the closing tag, so I'd just remove the whole thing.

Comment: It seems more likely  that this error is actually triggered by the existence of the first error. If you have error reporting turned on, and an error or notice is thrown before any action that tries to modify the headers, you'll get a "cannot modify headers" error because the reporting of the FIRST error counts as output.

Comment: That's a good point. But how would a deprecation notice trigger the second error?

Comment: Notices are echoed at exactly the point in execution where the code causes them, and the notices themselves become part of the output. The "headers already sent" error actually explicitly says where the output started --at exactly the same place that the first error occurred ("output started at ... functions.php:3551"). So the notice was spit out, and then some other action tried to modify the headers in some way. If the notice hadn't been echoed, no output would have been sent yet, and the second error wouldn't have been triggered. Make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain.